# ValueError: Lengths must match to compare (Pandas)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am working with a dataframe of 2 columns, the first with times, listed by [0, 3, 6, 9, 12, 15, 18, 21] repeated over 728 rows. The second column lists temperatures in Celsius. Here is what it looks like:

[Dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yTCyL.png)

I am trying to convert the temp values corresponding with time values of 3 and 6 to NaN. My code for this is:

`df2.loc[(df2['time'] == [3, 6]), 'temp'] = np.nan`

This however returns an error "Lengths must match to compare"

What am I missing here?

Comment: Try `df2.loc[(df2['time'].isin([3, 6]), 'temp'] = np.nan`

Answer (score 0):

You can't compare **df2['time']** with list. Instead one can use

```
df2.loc[((df2['time'] == 3) | (df2['time'] == 6)), 'temp'] = np.nan
```

Or as suggested by Joe Carboni in the comments one can use **isin**

```
df2.loc[df2['time'].isin([3,6]),'temp']
```

Comment: You can simplify this by using `isin()` --> `df2.loc[df2['time'].isin([3,6]),'temp'] = np.nan`